# How can I hold my excel screen before saving

Tags: excel, vba

The below code is to format excel files opened in taskbar. it is doing my work very nicely. butt i want to hold my screen at highlighted step for a while so that i can check the result. can anyone gimme some idea???

```vb
Sub OpenAllWorkbooksnew()
    Set destWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim DestCell As Range

    Dim cwb As Workbook
    For Each cwb In Workbooks

        **Call donemovementReport**
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next cwb
End Sub
```

Comment: sleep kind of idea? http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=626

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a breakpoint: http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s196/breakpoints.htm

It isn't the cleanest way but if this spreadsheet is just for you to use then this is a very simple and effective method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stop` to pause the code. For example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print "1"

    Stop

    Debug.Print "2"
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry siddarth its not fufiling my needs. i am trying stop that saving window for a while. which comes due to activeworkbook.close true

Comment: I don't see any code in your post which brings up the Save Window? `activeworkbook.close true` doesn't bring up the save window unless you are trying to do a `SaveAs` to overwrite a file or your `ActiveWorkbook` is `ReadOnly` In such a case you can call `Stop` just before that line

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over each workbook, you could create a named range in each called "Checked" and change your code as follows...

```
Sub OpenAllWorkbooksnew()
    Set destWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim DestCell As Range

    Dim cwb As Workbook
    For Each cwb In Workbooks

        'ensure "Checked" flag is reset
        cwb.Names("Checked").RefersToRange.Value = "Unchecked"

        'bring workbook to focus
        cwb.Activate

        'wait until "Checked" flag is changed to "OK"
        Do Until cwb.Names("Checked").RefersToRange.Value <> "Unchecked"
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'check result and action accordingly
        If UCase(cwb.Names("Checked").RefersToRange.Value) = "OK" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        ElseIf UCase(cwb.Names("Checked").RefersToRange.Value) = "ERROR" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        End If
    Next cwb
End Sub
```

If you don't have such a level of control over each workbook being looped through, then the same method could work but using the Ribbon/Commandbar (depending on your version of Excel).  It's difficult to be anymore specific without additional information on how exactly this code is being called, etc.